# How to solve a double integral with any code?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration, numerical-computing

I have an double integral:

[image: $$\int_0^{\infty} y^2 e^{\int_0^y e^{-x^2} d x} d y$$]

Because `exp(−^2)` is a non-integrable function, I have tried to solve this using the `quadgk` function in MATLAB, but I don't get a good result. Changing the integral's upper limit from infinity to some exact value may be a good compromise.

I had fitted

[image: $${\int_0^y e^{-x^2} d x}$$]

with a polynomial fitting, so the whole formula can be analytic. However, sometimes the polynomial fitting is badly conditioned, so I need a better idea to get a better solution.

Comment: Please update your question to be more explicit with what you are looking for – as is, it's a bit open ended. It's also hard for users to help you without a better understanding of h(y) and g(x). Can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: Also, have you tried [`integral`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) instead of `quadgk`?

Comment: to Leo_ma, hi, why don't you try to 1st solve int(,y,g,x) and then put that solution, using parameters, into the outer integral? Also, you mention h and g are 'complicated'. How complicated can they be? Mission Impossible? complicated, impossible, problemo, danger, may-do-boom .. whatever : if you divide complicated problems into smaller simpler ones, and put enough know-how and effort, it may even all turn out to be a walk in the park.

Comment: to horchler, thanks for your comment, and I have already provide a minimal example.

Comment: to john BG, now I have the feeling to be a walk in the park after divided the complicated problems. thanks for your advise.

Comment: Using the Symbolic toolbox you can show that `syms x y real;` `int(exp(-x^2),x,0,y)` returns `(pi^(1/2)*erf(y))/2`.

Comment: However, you'll see that `int(y^2*int(exp(-x^2),x,0,y),y,0,Inf)` returns `Inf`. So, as specified your integral is unbounded. If you replace the upper bound of the outer integral with a free parameter, e.g., `a`, you can obtain and expression in terms of that variable: `(exp(-a^2)*(a^2 + 1))/6 + (a^3*pi^(1/2)*erf(a))/6 - 1/6`.

Comment: to john BG,I confirmed your method to solve the int(y^2*int(exp(-x^2),x,0,y),y,0,a), that's right. But you lack 'exp' before 2nd int, after adding, the integral should be int(y^2.*exp(int(exp(-x^2),x,0,y)),y,0,a),and returns int(y^2*exp((pi^(1/2)*erf(y))/2), y, 0, a). if a equals 20, the return is int(y^2*exp((pi^(1/2)*erf(y))/2), y, 0, 20).  that's not an exact number. what should we do?

Comment: Here is the another method to solve the double integral to get an exact number(a=20):(https://github.com/saicma/fundamental_example/blob/main/double_integral.m), return 2.593240654688026e+04.@horchler@John BG

Comment: @Leo_ma sorry, missed that extra `exp`. See my answer below for how to evaluate this numerically or symbolically.

Comment: Your link returns "404 Not Found" for me - seems to be a private repo maybe? My answer below also returns a different value that you obtained for `a=20`. I get `6.4689e+03`.

Comment: sorry, my link is a private repo, you can't to access. Otherwise my old code's answer was wrong compared with your answer.  so I corrected it . My answer below returns the same value that you obtained for a=20. I also get 6.4689e+03. Last but not least, your answer is so pretty and correct, it help me a lot. thanks! @horchler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this numerically using two calls to [`integral`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) like this:

```
g=@(x)exp(-x.^2);
h=@(y)y.^2;
a=20;
z=integral(@(y)h(y).*exp(integral(g,0,y)),0,a,'ArrayValued',true);
```

You need to use the [`'ArrayValued'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html#expand_panel_heading_btbbkta-1-ArrayValued) option on the outer call to `integral` to force the function to run in a non-vectorized mode so the underlying algorithm doesn't try to pass a vector argument in which would be invalid for the upper integration limit of the inner integral.

And you can verify this result symbolically using Matlab's Symbolic Math toolbox and either [`vpa`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) or `double` to evaluate the integral:

```
syms x y real;
g=exp(-x^2);
h=y^2;
a=20;

z=int(h*exp(int(g,x,0,y)),y,0,a)
vpa(z)    % evaluate and output as variable precision arithmetic
double(z) % evaluate and output as floating point
```

Answer (score 0):

### without using any int function,this solve the double integral from zero to a(here a equals 20);

```
clear;clc;
N = 1e7;
a=20;
h = a/N;
x = 0:h:a;
y = x;

z = zeros(size(x));
for i = 2:N+1
    z(i) = z(i-1) + exp(-y(i-1)^2)*h;
end
%parameter z(end) means int(exp(-x^2),0,a) 

%the integrand means the bulk of integrand which can be express  
%any uplimit below a;
integrand = y.^2 .* exp(z);

%It just like the definite integral meanning expresses area as a 
%combination of infinitely many vertically-oriented rectangles. 
result= h *sum(integrand(1:end));
disp(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Please try to enrich it with some more comments on what the your code is doing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).